# Couchbase + N1QL

Tags: nosql, couchdb

Em um banco de aproximadamente 300.000 registros, a consulta abaixo:

`SELECT count(usuario) FROM analytics where 
    datahora.entrada >= '2016-11-18T00:00:00.000Z' and 
    datahora.entrada <= '2016-11-18T99:99:99.999Z' limit 5000`

demora aproximadamente 1 min, utilizando n1ql seria possível otimiza-la utilizando indices? Tentei fazer como abaixo mas não surtiu efeito

`` CREATE INDEX `ANALYTICS_datahora-entrada` ON `analytics`((`datahora`.`entrada`)) WHERE (`_type` = "analytics") USING GSI ``

Answer (score 0):

Utilizamos esse banco em uma aplicação de extrema importância para nosso cliente. Infelizmente tivemos infinitos problemas. Esse Sync para de funcionar do nada, quando você menos espera o ocorre  building dos índices consumindo 100% se cpu e deixando a aplicação inoperante. Temos a licença enterprise. Trocamos  nossa arquitetura para SQL e o nosso sistema ficou extremamente melhor e performático. Avalie a possibilidade de não utilizar esse banco, certamente quando vc mais precisar ele deixará vc na mão.